Number of copies of graph on a selected edge
In this proof of the Random Ramsey theorem, in the proof of Corollary 2.2, they state on any given edge in $K_n$, for some $n$,is contained in at most
$( 2e_F \cdot n^{v_F - 2} $) copies of $F$ for every graph $F$.
I kind of understand where the $n^{v_F - 2}$ part of this bound comes from - there are $v_F - 2$ vertices to choose from out of the remaining vertices not included in the edge, but then it appears to me should be $n-2\choose {v_F - 2}$ - and you multiply it by $e_F$, as the selected edge can fulfill one of $e_F$ positions, as an edgein the copy of the graph F.
But then it seems the upper bound should be $\binom{n-2}{{v_F - 2}}\cdot e_F$ - where does the $2$ coefficient come from, and how does the $n$ term come about?
(this bound is also mentioned in page 134 of the proof, if you want a clearer example)

Observe that $\binom{n-2}{v_{F}-2}\leq n^{v_{F}-2}$. This is a pretty crude, but common, upper bound for binomial coefficients in general. You're on the right track with why we are multiplying by $e_{F}$. The factor of $2$ comes from the fact that an edge can be mapped to two  vertices in two ways, i.e., if $e = uv$ is an edge of $F$, and $x, y$ are vertices in the complete graph, $u$ can be mapped to $x$ or $y$, and $v$ to $y$ or $x$.

Thanks a lot! Can't believe I didn't see the factor of 2 thing
